# OneToMany attribute not returning all the elements of its set

Tags: spring, hibernate, one-to-many

In my current spring project, I have this classes with a OneToMany attribute:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model implements UserDetails {
...
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "role")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<UserRole> roles;
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Role extends Model {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UserRole> user;
    ...
}
```

with the relation UserRole being implemented this way:

```
@Entity
public class UserRole {
  @EmbeddedId
    private UserRoleId id;

  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_role", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Role role;

  @Column
    private Date expirationDate;
...
}
```

the data for class Role and UserRole are inserted on the database via `data.sql` file included on the application classpath (`/src/main/resources`):

```
insert into role (name) values ('role_name');
insert into permission (name) values ('permission_name');
insert into role_permissions values (..., ...);
...
insert into user_role (fk_role, fk_role) values (1,1);
```

When I run the application, the Authentication object managed by the SecurityContext are filled correctly with the permissions associated with the roles I inserted, which make me assume the roles are all correctly inserted on the database.

But when I try list the roles on this view:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/roles", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'consult_'+#this.this.name)")
  public String formRoles(Model model, @RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
    model.addAttribute("command", serv.findBy("id", id));
    return "form_roles";
  }
```

html:

```
  <strong>roles</strong>
  <p th:text="${#sets.size(command.roles)}"></p>
  <ul>
    <li th:each="c : ${command.roles}" th:text="${c}"></li>
  </ul>
```

only one role are listed, instead of all 9 i have inserted in the file `data.sql`.  Anyone can  give a hint of what could be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

my service class:

```
  public E findBy(String key, Object value) {
    return dao.findBy(key, value);
  }
```

my dao class:

```
  public E findBy(String key, Object value) {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    List<E> lista = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM "+clazz.getSimpleName()+" a WHERE a."+key+" = :value").setParameter("value", value).getResultList();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();

    if(!lista.isEmpty())
      return (E) lista.get(0);
    else
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: what does serv.findBy("id", id) do internally?

Comment: calls the service, and that one calls my dao class (code for this methods added to the question)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting sql logs to true and see what is the query being fired, try running the same query from DB client. Which DB are you using?

Your DAO class why it is returning an element instead of the list fetched from below code.

```
public E findBy(String key, Object value) 


List<E> lista = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM "+clazz.getSimpleName()+" a WHERE a."+key+" = :value").setParameter("value", value).getResultList();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Sorry i don't have enough reps to add this as a comment.

Comment: I am using hsqldb right now. the Dao class should return the element with its associated attributes marked as `FetchType.EAGER` for what I know.

Comment: IMO Issue is with the code below from findBy method in your dao

if(!lista.isEmpty())
      return (E) lista.get(0);
    else
      return null;

The above code will return only one element i.e. lista.get(0);

Comment: Do you have a sugestion of how to fix? For what I know, it should read from the database the element itself and the attributes from it, no?

Comment: But it is supposed to return only one element: `serv.findBy("id", id)` should return one user; this user element should be returned with all the roles associated to it. Or I am wrong?

Comment: 1. Can you post the query hibernate fires, please set show sql to true.
2. Also please post the value of user and userrole retuned by findby method.